# Why do these snippets of JavaScript behave differently even though they both encounter an error?

Tags: javascript, operators, order-of-execution

```js
var a = {}
var b = {}

try{
  a.x.y = b.e = 1 // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'y' of undefined
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
console.log(b.e) // 1
```

```js
var a = {}
var b = {}

try {
  a.x.y.z = b.e = 1 // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}

console.log(b.e) // undefined
```

Comment: @NinaScholz: I don't understand. There is no syntax error; so I would assume that `b.z = 1` and `b.e = 1` execute first (given right-associativity on `=`), then `a.x.y.z = ...` execute and fail; why does `b` assignment pass in one case but not in the other?

Comment: @NinaScholz We agree that the property `y` does not exist on `a.x`; but that is true in both cases. Why does it prevent the right-hand-side assignment in the second case but not the first? What is different in the order of execution? (I mentioned Syntax error because the timing on the syntax error is very different from that of a runtime error.)

Comment: @Amadan after running code you will get error, and than use than type variable name again to see value

Comment: Found this describe how Javascript proceed assignment operation
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13

Comment: What do *you* think the difference is? Did you try to reason this out before asking? What did your research turn up? In other words, did you do your homework before asking?

Comment: It's interesting from a theoretical perspective, but this definitely falls under the "this is why you don't write code like that" category of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Actually, if you read the error message properly, case 1 and case 2 throw different errors.

Case `a.x.y`:

> Cannot **set** property 'y' of undefined

Case `a.x.y.z`:

> Cannot **read** property 'y' of undefined

I guess it's best to describe it by step-by-step execution in easy English.

**Case 1**

```js
// 1. Declare variable `a`
// 2. Define variable `a` as {}
var a = {}

// 1. Declare variable `b`
// 2. Define variable `b` as {}
var b = {}

try {

  /**
   *  1. Read `a`, gets {}
   *  2. Read `a.x`, gets undefined
   *  3. Read `b`, gets {}
   *  4. Set `b.z` to 1, returns 1
   *  5. Set `a.x.y` to return value of `b.z = 1`
   *  6. Throws "Cannot **set** property 'y' of undefined"
   */
  a.x.y = b.z = 1
  
} catch(e){
  console.error(e.message)
} finally {
  console.log(b.z)
}
```

**Case 2**

```js
// 1. Declare variable `a`
// 2. Define variable `a` as {}
var a = {}

// 1. Declare variable `b`
// 2. Define variable `b` as {}
var b = {}

try {

  /**
   *  1. Read `a`, gets {}
   *  2. Read `a.x`, gets undefined
   *  3. Read `a.x.y`, throws "Cannot **read** property 'y' of undefined".
   */
  a.x.y.z = b.z = 1
  
} catch(e){
  console.error(e.message)
} finally {
  console.log(b.z)
}
```

In comments, [Solomon Tam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4692464/solomon-tam) found [this ECMA documentation about assignment operation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13).

Answer (score 57):

The order of operations is clearer when you exploit the comma operator inside bracket notation to see which parts are executed when:

```js
var a = {}
var b = {}

try{
 // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'y' of undefined
  a
    [console.log('x'), 'x']
    [console.log('y'), 'y']
    = (console.log('right hand side'), b.e = 1);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
console.log(b.e) // 1
```

```js
var a = {}
var b = {}

try {
  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
  a
    [console.log('x'), 'x']
    [console.log('y'), 'y']
    [console.log('z'), 'z']
    = (console.log('right hand side'), b.e = 1);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}

console.log(b.e) // undefined
```

Looking at the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1):

> **The production `AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression` is evaluated as follows:**
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 3. Let rval be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 4. Throw a SyntaxError exception if... (irrelevant)
> 5. Call `PutValue(lref, rval)`.

`PutValue` is what throws the `TypeError`:

> 1. Let O be `ToObject(base)`.
> 2. If the result of calling the `[[CanPut]]` internal method of O with argument P is false, then
>
>    a. If Throw is true, then throw a TypeError exception.

Nothing can be assigned to a property of `undefined` - the `[[CanPut]]` internal method of `undefined` will always return `false`.

In other words: the interpreter parses the left-hand side, then parses the right-hand side, *then* throws an error if the property on the left-hand side can't be assigned to.

When you do

```
a.x.y = b.e = 1
```

The left hand side is *successfully parsed* up until `PutValue` is called; the fact that the `.x` property evaluates to `undefined` is not considered until after the right-hand side is parsed. The interpreter sees it as "Assign some value to the property "y" of undefined", and assigning to a property of `undefined` only throws inside `PutValue`.

In contrast:

```
a.x.y.z = b.e = 1
```

The interpreter never gets to the point where it tries to assign to the `z` property, because it first must resolve `a.x.y` to a value. If `a.x.y` resolved to a value (even to `undefined`), it would be OK - an error would be thrown inside `PutValue` like above. But *accessing* `a.x.y` throws an error, because property `y` cannot be accessed on `undefined`.

Comment: Nice comma operator trick--never thought to use it that way (for debugging only, of course)!

Comment: s/parse/evaluate/

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code:

```js
var a = {};
a.x.y = console.log("evaluating right hand side"), 1;
```

The rough outline of steps required to execute the code is as follows <sup>[ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)</sup>:

1. Evaluate the left hand side. Two things to keep in mind:

   - Evaluating an expression is not the same as getting the value of expression.
   - Evaluating a property accessor <sup>[ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation)</sup> e.g. `a.x.y` returns a reference <sup>[ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type)</sup> consisting of base value `a.x` (undefined) and referenced name (`y`).
2. Evaluate the right hand side.
3. Get the value of result obtained in step 2.
4. Set the value of the reference obtained in step 1 to the value obtained in step 3 i.e. set property `y` of undefined to the value. This is supposed to throw a TypeError exception <sup>[ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-putvalue)</sup>.