# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined even when using typeof- better approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, undefined

My loop checks if an array of cards has a special attribute, if so it does a certain action.

```js
  if(typeof cardArray[i]['special']!=='undefined'){
    // do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, even though I'm using typeof to check the array contains a defined special key I'm still getting

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'special')*

What am I doing wrong here or is there a better approach for this in general?

Comment: Are you looking for [Optional chaining (`?.`)](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)?

Comment: If special is undefined, are you sure that `i` isn't going past the bounds of the array?

Comment: Once you need to check all your array elements have values because value at some index of array is coming undefined.

Comment: It's `cardArray[i]` that's undefined, not `cardArray[i]['special']`. The error is because you're attempting to access `undefined.special`.

Comment: Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54646467/6532549). _Disclaimer: I wrote the accepted answer._

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your problem is probably inside your loop.
Take a look at this example running without errors:

```js
const cardArray = [{
  'special': 'pasta'
  }, {
  'regular': 'bread'
}]

for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Loop number ${i}`)
  if(typeof cardArray[i]['special']!=='undefined'){
    console.log(`Found: ${cardArray[i]['special']}`)
  }
}
```